# Local functions accessing variables outside

Tags: function, rust

[A local function in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26685666/a-local-function-in-rust/26685687) shows how to make a local function that does not access variables.

This function fails because it accesses `v`:

```
// Assume v takes up 1 GB and is slow to compute
let v = [1,2,3];
fn recursive(x:usize) {
  if x - v.len() > 0 {
      // do stuff that may involve calling recursive() and change v
      recursive(x-1);
  }
}
recursive(8);
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest option is to pass the state into the recursive function by (mutable) reference:

```
let mut v = [1, 2, 3];
fn recursive(v: &mut [i32], x: usize) {
    if x - v.len() > 0 {
        // do stuff that may involve calling recursive() and change v
        recursive(v, x - 1);
    }
}
recursive(&mut v, 8);
```

Answer (score 0):

A [closure](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html) can access local variables, but do not support recursion.
You can try to use loop instead or something like Y combinator.